# Can't create instance of BingMapsDirectionsTask after adding using statements

Tags: c#, windows, task, bing-maps

I have researched everywhere with no result. I am creating a windows mobile application using "Microsoft Visual Express 2010 windows phone, c#". I require a map providing directions between two locations.

I have been following this link "http://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/windows-phone-75/9781849687249/ch03s09.html".

I have added using statements Microsoft.Phone.Tasks; and System.Device.Locations;
When I go to create an instance of "BingMapsDirectionsTask" it only gives me the option to create a class and does not acknowledge it as a reference to phone.Task using statement.

I have a BingMap displaying included with my reference key !
I am cracking up with trying to get Bing Maps to work :(!!

Thanks (fingers crossed)!!

Comment: Which version of WP are you targeting 7, 8 or 8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, WP7 did not have the BingMapsDirectionsTask when it was originaly released. According to the documentation it was added to WP7.1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.bingmapsdirectionstask(v=vs.105).aspx Ensure you have updated your development environment and that your app targets WP7.1.

All that said, the WP7 market share is really small and unlikely to grow. You should target WP8 or above.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated, they don't call you the "king" for no reason ;)!!